# Regular expression to fetch beginning of string or a symbol

Tags: javascript, regex

I am writing a function to find attributes value from given string and given attribute name.

The input stings look like those below:

`sip:+19999999999@trunkgroup2:5060;user=phone
<sip:+19999999999;tgrp=0180401;trunk-context=aaaa.aaaa.ca@10.10.10.100:8000;user=phone;transport=udp>
<sip:19999999999;tgrp=0306001;trunk-context=aaaa.aaaa.ca@10.10.10.100:8000;transport=udp>
<sip:+19999999999;tgrp=SMPPDIN;trunk-context=aaaa.aaaa.ca@10.10.10.100:8000;transport=udp>`

After few hours I came out with this regular expression: `/(\Wsip[:,+,=]+)(\w+)/g`, but this is not working for the first example - as there is no not a word character before the attributes name.

How can I fix this expression to fetch both cases - `<sip...` and `sip..` only when it is the beginning of the string.

I use this function to extract both `sip` and `tgrp` values.

Comment: Replace `\W` with `\b` (word boundary). See https://regex101.com/r/ILeklm/2.

Comment: Use the one or none condition `?`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `\W` with `\b`, and use

```
\b(sip[:+=]+)(\w+)
```

Or, to match at the beginning of a string:

```
^\W?(sip[:+=]+)(\w+)
```

See the [first regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ILeklm/3) and the [second regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KNEujb/1).

As `\W` is a consuming pattern matching any non-word char (a char other than a letter/digit/`_`) you won't have a match at the start of the string. A `\b` word boundary will match at the start of the string and in case there is a non-word char before `s`.

If you **literally**  need to find a match at the beginning of a string after an optional non-word char, the `\W` must be replaced with `^\W?` where `^` match the start of a string, and `\W?` matches 1 or 0 non-word chars.

Also, note that `,` inside a character class is matched as a literal `,`. If you mean to use it to enumerate chars, you should remove it.

**Pattern details**:

- `\b` - a word boundary

  OR
- `^` - start of string
- `\W?` - 1 or 0 (due to the `?` quantifier) non-word chars (i.e. chars other than letters/digits and `_`)
- `(sip[:+=]+)` - Group 1: `sip` substring followed with one or more `:`, `+` or `=` chars
- `(\w+)` - Group 2: one or more word chars.

Comment: Thanks! I did remove the `,` at some stage, but looks like I did not copy the latest expression.

Comment: Still I used the `\b`. I do create the regex string using parameter passed to the function. The parameter is either `sip` or `tgrp`. In this case `^\W?(sip[:+=]+)(\w+)` will not work.

Comment: @Bobbie So, I was right from the ver beginning you are looking to match the string after any non-word char or at the start of the string. Thank you for letting know.

Answer (score 1):

for begining of line use `^` and to make `<` is optional use `?`

```
^<?(sip[:,+,=]+)(\w+)
```